# Does linear logic have truth tables?

Tags: logic, programming

Classical logic have truth tables and there are complete truth tables for the binary logical operators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table , i.e. classical logical operators already exhaust all the possible function of the 2 variables. But there is linear logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic with additional connectives. So - does linear logic have truth tables and do some of the linear connectives equate with the classical binary operators?

My question is connected with the production rule systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm. Of course the production rule systems are based on the classical logic and that is why the facts are joined by the classical connectives in them. But what about linear production systems? Can be join facts using the linear connectives and arrive at the linear production systems in turn?